# Определить место человека в рейтинге

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, на сайте есть таблица с рейтингом, мне нужно найти номер места человека в таблице. Для этого я беру балл пользователя записываю в переменную, и беру кол-во баллов каждого пользователя с таблицы и вношу их в список. Потом сверяю балл пользователя с баллами людей, и вывожу в тег.

```
var num_reyt = 0;
var score = $('.xdget-trainingAchievements .badge').html().split(' ')[0];
var ar = document.querySelectorAll(".user-rating tbody td:nth-child(2)");
var spisok = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    content = ar[i].innerText
    spisok.push(content);
}

for (var m = 0; m < spisok.length; i++) {
    if (spisok[m] == score) {
        num_reyt = m + 1;
        break;
    }

}
$(".scn").text(num_reyt);
```

Скрипт не выдает ошибки, но и результата не выдает. Тег .scn остается пустой, точнее там записан 0, так как изначально я дал ему значение равное нулю, из этого делаю предположение что ошибка кроется, в for.

Comment: Выведи во втором цикле значение для `spisok[m]` и `score`.

Comment: Выдает числа которые в таблице и число баллов пользователя

Comment: Так же когда я ввожу этот код в консоли именно на сайте, то изменения срабатывают в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в i++ вместо m++

Должно быть так

```
for (var m = 0; m < spisok.length; m++) {
```